# Method not called, debug message not displayed

Tags: java, methods, indentation

Basically, everything works in seclusion, but for some reason at the end of my generateBoard method, it doesn't actually call the method (printBoard) to print it. I believe that this should work but not even my debug message is popping up so I imagine I have an indentation error somewhere?

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Zombies {
    private int Level = 1;
    private int MoveNo = 0;
    public static char[][] myGrid = new char[12][12];

        public static void levelInfection() {
            Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
            System.out.println("How many infected tiles would you like to start the game with?");
            if(input.hasNextInt()) {
                int nLevel = input.nextInt();
                if(nLevel > 6) {
                    System.out.println("You can't have that many infected tiles, you'd never survive!");
                    levelInfection();
                }
                else if (nLevel < 0){
                    System.out.println("You need to have some infected tiles, and don't try any negative numbers!");
                    levelInfection();
                }
                else if (nLevel < 6 && nLevel > 0) {
                    System.out.println("We will now create your gameboard with " + nLevel + " infected tiles, good luck!");
                    generateBoard(nLevel);
                }
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("I'm sorry, you didn't enter an integer number. Please try again.");
                levelInfection();
            }
        }

    public static void generateBoard(int nLevel) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int i, j;
        int infTile = 0;

        for(i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            for(j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
                if (i == 6 && j == 6) {
                    myGrid[i][j] = 'P';
                    System.out.println("I made a player tile");
                }
                else if(rand.nextInt(9) == 0) {
                    if(myGrid[i][j] == 'I'||infTile >= nLevel) {
                        System.out.println("I found infected tile");
                        return;
                    }
                    else {
                        myGrid[i][j] = 'I';
                        System.out.println("I made an infected tile");
                        infTile++;
                        System.out.println("I counted an infected tile (" + infTile +") at " + i + "," + j);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    myGrid[i][j] = 'x';
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Print me mofo!");
        printBoard();
    }

    public static void printBoard() {
        int i, j;
        for(i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            for(j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
                if(j == 0) {
                    System.out.print( "| " );
                }
                System.out.print( myGrid[i][j] + " " );
                if(j == 11) {
                    System.out.print( "|\n" );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good to know: identation doesn't matter all that much in java, it primarily serves to make it more readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps it is hitting your `return` statement

```
  if(myGrid[i][j] == 'I'||infTile >= nLevel) {
    System.out.println("I found infected tile");
    return;
  }
```

...which would exit the method without ever reaching the call.

Comment: You're correct, I thought that it would only break that if - else cycle and then carry on.

How can I now stop that if statement but not the whole method?

Comment: `break`, instead of `return` would break out of the wholec current loop

Comment: @user3053362 I suggest to call printBoard() outside generateBoard, for the principle of do one thing and generally for better clean code.

Comment: If I was to do that, I'd have to create some kind of delay between calling the generating method and then the building method which is more effort than worth by the looks of it.

Comment: That's only the case if they run concurrently. If you call them one after another the second isn't called until the first is complete.

Answer (score 1):

When you are finding the infected tile, you have put up a return statement in the execution order. This returns the control to the caller function terminating the execution of `generateBoard()`.

If you need the value of you array at that instant when you encounter the infected tile, you should go for a `break;` statement. This would break out of the current for loop but the rest of the function will still execute.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's brilliant, I had it backwards! The only problem now is that I'm getting blank cells in my grid for some reason?